# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: annotations.Users

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, entity

Consider the hierarchy :

[image]

And the following classes and xml :

**HibernateUtil.java**

```
package annotations;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;


/**
 * 
 * @author X3
 *
 */
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
    private static final String HIBERNATE_CFG = "hibernateAnnotations.cfg.xml";

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() 
    {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration().addResource(HIBERNATE_CFG).configure();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().
                applySettings(cfg.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

**Users.java**

```
package annotations;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private long userID;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "MessageTimeDate", nullable = false)
    private java.sql.Timestamp datetime;

    @Column(name = "UserMessage", nullable = false)
    private String message;



    public Users(String username , String message)
    {
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        this.datetime = new Timestamp(date.getTime());

        this.username = username;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public long getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(long userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public java.sql.Timestamp getDatetime() {
        return datetime;
    }

    public void setDatetime(java.sql.Timestamp datetime) {
        this.datetime = datetime;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

**Main.java**

```
package annotations;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try
        {
               SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
               Session session = sf.openSession();
               session.beginTransaction();

               Users user1 = new Users("Jack" , "Hello");
               session.save(user1);
               session.getTransaction().commit();
               session.close();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            e.getStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

And **hibernateAnnotations.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CHAT_DB</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class="annotations.Users"></mapping>       
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

When I run main(), the following error appears in output window :

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: annotations.Users
```

But the entity `Users` is in `annotations` package , so what's wrong ?

Comment: Could you commit the considered structure to the github or some other online source repository so we could check it out and try running?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The Hibernate configuration file must define the entity classes:

```
<mapping class="annotations.Users"/>
```

Or you must explicitly add the class to the configuration using

```
configuration.addClass(annotations.Users.class)
// Read mappings as a application resourceName
 // addResource is for add hbml.xml files in case of declarative approach
configuration.addResource("myFile.hbm.xml");  // not hibernateAnnotations.cfg.xml
```

Comment: This is very weird , since it makes me to use another XML file , where the entire idea of Hibernate Annotations is to avoid them , except using the `hibernateAnnotations.cfg.xml` , of course .

Comment: @ron addresource method is used for hbm files not for hibernate configuration cfg.xml file, if you are using declarative approach then you should use this other wise not. No need of this method if you are using annotation approcah

Comment: I already have this : `<mapping class="annotations.Users"/>
` in `hibernateAnnotations.cfg.xml` , still same result .

Comment: plus one, adding "<mapping resource="myFile.hbm.xml"/>" in hibernate.cfg.xml also worked

Comment: if you can't get it to work in hibernate.cfg.xml,  try configuration.addAnnotatedClass  NOT configuration.addClass

Comment: @OneSolitaryNoob  This also worked for me.  Much appreciated.

Comment: You can't make it run directly by using code mentioned in the answer, you have to follow comment of @OneSolitaryNoob. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 17):

When I was trying to rewrite my example (from tutorialspoint) to use annotations, I got the same exception. This helped me (addAnnotatedClass()):

```
Configuration cfg=new Configuration(); 
cfg.addAnnotatedClass(com.tutorialspoint.hibernate.entity.Employee.class);
cfg.configure();
```

Comment: Given that the Entity class is annotated this is the correct answer - question mentions no hbm.xml file

Comment: @OneSolitaryNoob mentioned it above as well but this worked for me.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 13):

**I did not find the accepted answer helpful in resolving the exception encountered in my code.**  And while not technically incorrect, I was also not satisfied with others' suggestions to introduce redundancy:

- programmatically re-add the mapped class using `configuration.addAnnotatedClass(...)`
- create a `hbm.xml` file and resource mapping in `hibernate_test.cfg.xml` that were redundant to the existing annotations
- scan the package where the (already mapped) class exists using external dependencies not mentioned in the original question

***However, I found 2 possible solutions that I wanted to share, both of which independently resolved the exception I encountered in my own code.***

I was having the same `MappingException` as @ron (using a very nearly identical `HibernateUtil` class):

```
public final class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = null;

    private HibernateUtil() {}

    public static synchronized SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if ( sessionFactory == null ) {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate_test.cfg.xml");
            serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                    .build();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory( serviceRegistry );
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
// exception handling and closeSessionFactory() omitted for brevity
}
```

Within my `hibernate_test.cfg.xml` configuration file, I have the required class mapping:

```
<mapping class="myPackage.Device"/>
```

And my `Device` class is properly annotated with the `javax.persistence.Entity` annotation:

```
package myPackage.core;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table( name = "devices" )
public class Device {
    //body omitted for brevity
}
```

***Two Possible Solutions:***

***First***, I am using Hibernate 5.2, and for those using Hibernate 5 this solution using a `Metadata` object to build a `SessionFactory` should work.  It also appears to be the currently recommended [native bootstrap mechanism](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-native) in the [Hibernate Getting Started Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/quickstart/html_single/) :

```
public static synchronized SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if ( sessionFactory == null ) {

        // exception handling omitted for brevity

        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure("hibernate_test.cfg.xml")
                .build();

        sessionFactory = new MetadataSources( serviceRegistry )
                    .buildMetadata()
                    .buildSessionFactory();
    }
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

***Second***, while `Configuration` is [semi-deprecated in Hibernate 5](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#appendix-legacy-bootstrap), @ron didn't say which version of Hibernate he was using, so this solution could also be of value to some.

**I found a very subtle change in the order of operations when instantiating and configuring `Configuration` and `ServiceRegistry` objects to make all the difference in my own code.**

*Original order* (`Configuration` created and configured prior to `ServiceRegistry`):

```
public static synchronized SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if ( sessionFactory == null ) {

        // exception handling omitted for brevity

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate_test.cfg.xml");

        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings( configuration.getProperties() )
                .build();

        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory( serviceRegistry );
    }
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

*New order* (`ServiceRegistry` created and configured prior to `Configuration`):

```
public static synchronized SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if ( sessionFactory == null ) {

        // exception handling omitted for brevity

        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure("hibernate_test.cfg.xml")
                .build();

        sessionFactory = new Configuration().buildSessionFactory( serviceRegistry );
    }
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

At the risk of TLDR, I will also point out that with respect to `hibernate_test.cfg.xml` my testing suggests that the `configuration.getProperties()` method only returns `<property />` elements, and `<mapping />` elements are excluded.  This appears consistent with the specific use of the terms 'property' and 'mapping' within the [API documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#configure--) for `Configuration`.  I will concede that this behaviour may have something to do with the failure of `applySettings()` to yield the mapping data to the `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder`.  However, this mapping data should already have been parsed during configuration of the `Configuration` object and available to it when `buildSessionFactory()` is called.  Therefore, I suspect this may be due to implementation-specific details regarding resource precedence when a `ServiceRegistry` is passed to a `Configuration` object's `buildSessionFactory()` method.

I know this question is several years old now, but I hope this answer saves somebody the hours of research I spent in deriving it.  Cheers!

Comment: +1; I don't understand why your answer has not been appreciated! It gave me some valuable insight in a similar problem I was having. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Add the following to your xml:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>annotations</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I tried 1000... solutions suggested in a lot of posts...this is the one that worked for me. tnks!

Answer (score 6):

I was having same problem.

Use `@javax.persistence.Entity` instead of `org.hibernate.annotations.Entity`

Answer (score 5):

For those using Spring's Java configuration classes, you might write the following:

```
@Autowired
@Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
    sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(Foo.class);
    sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(Bar.class);
    sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(Bat.class);
    return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
}
```

Comment: Good answer, alternatively, if your entities are located in the same package/sub-packages, you could take advantage of the "scanPackages" method instead of adding the entities one by one. sessionBuilder.scanPackages("com.example.entities"); More info : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.html

Answer (score 4):

If your entity is mapped through annotations, add the following code to your configuration;

```
configuration.addAnnotatedClass(theEntityPackage.EntityClassName.class);
```

For example;

```
configuration.addAnnotatedClass(com.foo.foo1.Products.class);
```

if your entity is mapped with xml file, use addClass instead of addAnnotatedClass.

As an example;

```
configuration.addClass(com.foo.foo1.Products.class);
```

Ping me if you need more help.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue and I searched for almost 2 hours and tried with different possible ways like replacing old hibernate JARs and changing the DB table schema. But finally got the solution as below:

```
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(); //This line to be replaced with below commented line
```

Replace above for

```
//Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
//ServiceRegistry servReg = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();
//SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory(servReg);
```

It will then work fine..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using HibernateUtil.java, to create sessionfactory object, you should use this:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory=new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Because in order to avoid the exception, you'll have to declare the class object in HibernateUtil.java file as `configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Student_Info.class);` which looks dumb because we have provided the entry already in hibernate.cfg.xml file.

To use the AnnotationConfiguration class you'll have to add a jar to your project build path:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhibernate353jar.htm

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar issue and adding

```
 sessionFactory.setAnnotatedClasses(User.class);
```

this line helped but before that I was having

```
sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.rg.spring.model" });
```

I am not sure why that one is not working.User class is under com.rg.spring.model
Please let me know how to get it working via packagesToScan method.

Answer (score 0):

Define the `Entity` class in *Hibernate.cfg.xml*

```
<mapping class="com.supernt.Department"/>
```

While creating the `sessionFactory` object Load the *Configuration* file Like

```
SessionFactory factory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Thanks, I was also missing mapping tag in my configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      try{
        // factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
         factory = new AnnotationConfiguration().
                   configure().
                   //addPackage("com.xyz") //add package if used.
                   addAnnotatedClass(Employee.class).
                   buildSessionFactory();
      }catch (Throwable ex) { 
         System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
         throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
      }//you can write like this in your test class inside main method.this way you will be able to do the things using annotaions only
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to hibernate.cfg.xml

```
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the package name is given in the **property packagesToScan** in the dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"             class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="**entity package name here**"></property> 
        <property name="hibernateProperties">  
            <props>  
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>  
            </props>  
        </property>  
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **EntityScanner** if you can bear external dependency.It will inject your all entity classes seamlessly even from multiple packages. Just add following line after configuration setup.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();    
EntityScanner.scanPackages("com.fz.epms.db.model.entity").addTo(configuration);
// And following depencency if you are using Maven
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.v-ladynev</groupId>
        <artifactId>fluent-hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This way you don't need to declare all entities in hibernate mapping file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 5.0x version,configuration with standard service registry is **deprecated**.

Instead you should bootstrap it with **Metadata**:
In your HibernateUtil class, you should add

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {           
        StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .configure( "hibernate.cfg.xml" )
            .build();

        Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources( standardRegistry )
            .getMetadataBuilder()
            .build();

        return metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
    } catch(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it resolves by adding `configuration.addAnnotatedClass(com.myApp.model.Example.class);` after `Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(HibernateUtil.class.getResource("/hibernate.cfg.xml"));` in hibernateUtill class. 
It Read a mapping from the class annotation metadata .
Read more about `addAnnotatedClass()` from [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration.html#addAnnotatedClass(java.lang.Class)).

Answer (score 0):

Initially I trying with the below code which didn't work for me

```
MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry);
Metadata metadata = metadataSources.getMetadataBuilder().build();
SessionFactory sessionFactory= metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
```

For me below configuration worked. All the hibernate properties i provided from the code itself and using hibernate version 5+. I'm trying to connect to the Postgressql db.

imports:

```
 import org.hibernate.Session;
 import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
 import org.hibernate.Transaction;
 import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
 import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
 import org.hibernate.cfg.Environment;
 import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
```

code:

```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
    configuration.setProperty(Environment.DRIVER, "org.postgresql.Driver");
    configuration.setProperty(Environment.URL, lmsParams.getDbProperties().getDbURL());
    configuration.setProperty(Environment.USER, lmsParams.getDbProperties().getUsername());
    configuration.setProperty(Environment.PASS, lmsParams.getDbProperties().getPassword());

    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.release_mode", "auto");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    configuration.setProperty(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create");
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(LMSSourceTable.class);
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
            .build();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

**Latest Update**:
One more option worked for me using the **Reflections** package as a dependency. This i tried with both mysql and postgress and it works fine.

**Some info about Reflections:**
The Reflections library works as a classpath scanner. It indexes the scanned metadata and allows us to query it at runtime. It can also save this information, so we can collect and use it at any point during our project, without having to re-scan the classpath again

if you are using maven:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
<artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
<version>0.9.11</version>
</dependency>
```

code:

```
 MetadataSources metadataSources = new 
 MetadataSources(serviceRegistry);
 Reflections entityPackageReflections = new Reflections("com.company.abc.package.name");
    entityPackageReflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class).forEach(metadataSources::addAnnotatedClass);
    Metadata metadata = metadataSources.getMetadataBuilder().build();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory=  metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and the only thing that worked for me was to change the location of **hibernate.cfg.xml** to **src/main/resources**

Answer (score 0):

I fix this error by add in the .xml configuration property name="packagesToScan" with value="SCANN_YOUR_PACKAGE.controller.entity" to show a Hibernate where is the package of entity's.

```
<!--  Configu Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="SCANN_YOUR_PACKAGE.controller.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
              <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           </props>
        </property>
   </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Entity**
is **deprecated** then **error shows
**Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: Unknown entity: com.spring.orm.entities.Student; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.spring.orm.entities.Student**
**

> My Code is

```
package com.spring.orm.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student_details")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private int studentId;
    @Column(name = "student_name")
    private String studentName;
    @Column(name = "student_city")
    private String studentCity;

    public Student(int studentId, String studentName, String studentCity) {
        super();
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.studentCity = studentCity;
    }

    public Student() {

    }

    public int getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    public String getStudentCity() {
        return studentCity;
    }

    public void setStudentCity(String studentCity) {
        this.studentCity = studentCity;
    }

}
```

You can use **@javax.persistence.Entity** in place of **@Entity**

```
    package com.spring.orm.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;

@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "student_details")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private int studentId;
    @Column(name = "student_name")
    private String studentName;
    @Column(name = "student_city")
    private String studentCity;

    public Student(int studentId, String studentName, String studentCity) {
        super();
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.studentCity = studentCity;
    }

    public Student() {

    }

    public int getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    public String getStudentCity() {
        return studentCity;
    }

    public void setStudentCity(String studentCity) {
        this.studentCity = studentCity;
    }

}
```

**For more details you can see on my youtube channel**
https://youtu.be/uwLU65E4q3Y

Answer (score 0):

The exception occurs because hibernate can locate mapping file (someEntity.hbm.xml)

One of the solution is to add hbm xml file to configuration while generating session factory.

```
configuration.addResource("someEntity.hbm.xml");
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem occurs because of the entry `mapping class="annotations.Users"` in `hibernate.cfg.xml` remove that line then it will be work.

I had the same issue. When I removed the above line then it was working fine for me.