# Getting org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity. Using Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I have just started working in **java spring framework**. Am just trying to populate a simple table with columns id and a name. But am getting :

> Unknown entity: org.hibernate.MappingException

I get that it is commonly encountered exception. But I couldn't fix this. You can find the The entity, dao and hibernate config am using below.

HibernateConfig.java

```
 @Getter @Setter 
@Configuration@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "databaseConfiguration") 
public class HibernateConfig {
    @Value("${driverClass}")
    private String driverClass;

    @Value("${url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("username")
    private String username;

    @Value("password")
    private String password;

    @Value("${hibernateDialect}")
    private String hibernateDialect;

    @Value("${hbm2ddlAuto}")
    private String hbm2ddlAuto;

    private Integer minSize;

    private Integer maxSize;


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
       return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hbm2ddlAuto);
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
        properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", minSize);
        properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", maxSize);
        return properties;
   }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
       return sessionFactory;
}


    @Bean
    public ITestDao testDao() {
        ITestDao testDao = new TestDao();
       return testDao;
    }
}
```

All the properties are being taken from the .yml file. ITestDao is the interface with abstract add() method in it.

Entity class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "dump", nullable = false)
    private String dump;
}
```

Dao class

```
@Repository
@Transactional
@Getter
@Setter
public class TestDao implements ITestDao {

    @Autowired
    private LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean;


    public Test add(Test test) {
        try {
                sessionFactoryBean.getObject().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().begin();
            sessionFactoryBean.getObject().getCurrentSession().persist(test);

    } finally {
            sessionFactoryBean.getObject().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
    }
    return test;
    }

}
```

A service method will call this dao with `@Transactional` annotated above it. But while calling this `add()` dao method am getting Unknown entity:

> org.hibernate.MappingException

Comment: Post the exact and complete stack trace.

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23215605/3959856

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way :

```
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
         sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "my.package.model" });// You need to provide to adapt : my.package.model
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
       return sessionFactory;
}
```

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing below annotation.

```
@EntityScan("some.known.persistence")
```

The @EntityScan only identifies which classes should be used by a specific persistence context.

Comment: So I should pass the path of entity files as paramaeter to this @Entity scan right over the HibernateConfig class?