# Hibernate MappingException: Unknown entity: com.xxxxxx.service.model.$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy

Tags: hibernate, jpa, cdi, mappingexception

I'm using maven multimodule project.
I divided my logic into different layers, Presentation, Business logic, data layer, each one in a separate module(layer).
When I try to insert an object, this exception occurs:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.xxxxx.service.model.Object$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

I'm using CDI bean and the application is based on JSF2 and Hibernate.

Comment: show your code where you insert object and full exception

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214454/org-hibernate-mappingexception-unknown-entity-annotations-users

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem will happen when you have a JPA entity which is also declared as a CDI managed bean like below:

```
@Named // Or @XxxScoped
@Entity
public class YourEntity {}
```

And you attempt to persist the CDI managed bean instance itself like below:

```
@Inject
private YourEntity yourCDIManagedEntity;

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public void save() {
    entityManager.persist(yourCDIManagedEntity);
}
```

This is not the correct way. You should not make your entity a CDI managed bean. [A CDI managed bean is actually a proxy class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29651008/field-getobj-returns-all-nulls-on-injected-cdi-managed-beans-while-manually-i/29672591#29672591). You can clearly see this back in your exception message. It says it doesn't know the entity `com.xxxxx.service.model.Object$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy` instead of that it doesn't know the entity `com.xxxxx.service.model.Object`.

```
@Entity // NO @Named nor @XxxScoped!
public class YourEntity {}
```

And you should prepare it as a normal entity instance and then you can safely persist it as a normal entity.

```
private YourEntity yourNormalEntity;

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    yourNormalEntity = new YourEntity();
}

public void save() {
    entityManager.persist(yourNormalEntity);
}
```

Comment: Great BalusC . You solution is exactly what I need . It works for me now . Thank you.