# How to fix Hibernate Unknown entity exception?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have HibernateSesstion factory class for getting sesion

```
public class HibernateSessionFactory {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    protected static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(){

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        ServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .loadProperties("hibernate.properties").build();
        try {
            sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
        }catch (Exception e){
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
        if (sessionFactory.isClosed()){
            buildSessionFactory();
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

My entity class

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "user_commands")
public class UserCommands implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "chat_id")
    private Long chatId;
    @Column(name = "last_command")
    private String lastCommand;

    public Long getChatId() {
        return chatId;
    }

    public void setChatId(Long chatId) {
        this.chatId = chatId;
    }

    public String getLastCommand() {
        return lastCommand;
    }

    public void setLastCommand(String lastCommand) {
        this.lastCommand = lastCommand;
    }
}
```

And my function from class `UserCommandsRepository` which select some data

```
String sql = "update user_commands set last_command = :lastCommand where chat_id = :chatId";
Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.saveOrUpdate(userCommands);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

My hibernate.property file

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://URL
hibernate.connection.username=USERNAME
hibernate.connection.password=PASSWORD
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl=update
```

When I am trying to run my Main.java class, it's failing with error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: entity.UserCommands
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.entityPersister(MetamodelImpl.java:704)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1609)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.EntityState.getEntityState(EntityState.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:617)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:610)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:605)
    at repository.UserCommandsRepository.updateLastUserCommand(UserCommandsRepository.java:13)
    at highwayMotorsTelergramBot.Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: @SternK It's version 5.4.21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stated in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#appendix-legacy-bootstrap) the `Configuration` is semi-deprecated:

> `Configuration` is semi-deprecated but still available for use, in a limited form that eliminates these drawbacks. "Under the covers", `Configuration` uses the new bootstrapping code, so the things available there are also available here in terms of auto-discovery.

1. You can use new [native bootstrapping api](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-native) in the following way:

```java
StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
    .loadProperties("hibernate.properties")
    .build();
MetadataSources metadata = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry);
metadata.addAnnotatedClass(UserCommands.class);
// ...
Metadata meta = metadata.buildMetadata();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = meta.buildSessionFactory();
```

2. You can use [jpa bootstrapping](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-jpa) in the following way:

```java
HibernatePersistenceProvider provider = new HibernatePersistenceProvider();
EntityManagerFactory emFactory = provider.createEntityManagerFactory("CRM", null);

EntityManager em = emFactory.createEntityManager();
// ...
```

This assumes that you have `META-INF` folder in your class path and this folder contains the `persistence.xml` file like the following:

```xml
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="CRM">
        <description>Persistence unit for Hibernate User Guide</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>


        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://URL" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="USERNAME" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="PASSWORD" />
            
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="TEST_SCHEMA" />
            
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

In this case you should not manually list all your entities hibernate will pick up them automatically if they lies in the same jar with `persistence.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

You never tell Hibernate about your entity models. There are several ways to do this. You can do this via XML, the `Configuration` object or the `Session` object.

Check this for more [org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: annotations.Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214454/org-hibernate-mappingexception-unknown-entity-annotations-users)

Comment: How can I load hibernate  properties from `hibernate.properties` file and use function `.addAnnotatedClass`, cuz in example abowe is using cfg.xml file? As I undastand, `Configuration` class is using for xml configuration?