# Hibernate - MappingException - Unkown Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, session, saving-data

When trying to save Student using session, I get this error though I used

> .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)

in Configuration and used

> `<mapping class="com.hibernate_demo.models.Student"/>`

in Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.hibernate_demo.models.Student
at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.entityPersister(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:589)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1450)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:36)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:30)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:632)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:625)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:620)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:348)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy35.save(Unknown Source)
at com.hibernate_demo.application.CreateStudentDemo.main(CreateStudentDemo.java:24)
```

Student.java

```
package com.hibernate_demo.models;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
public class Student {

@Id
private long id;
@Column(name="first_name", nullable = false)
private String firstName;
@Column(name="last_name", nullable = false)
private String lastName;
@Column(name="email", nullable = false)
private String email;

public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
}

public Student() {}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            '}';
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property 
    name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Hibernate</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>

    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>

    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <mapping class="com.hibernate_demo.models.Student"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

CreateStudentDemo.java
package com.hibernate_demo.application;

```
import com.hibernate_demo.models.Student;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class CreateStudentDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create Session Factory
    SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
            .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
            .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
            .buildSessionFactory();

    // Using session object to save Java object
    try (factory; Session session = factory.getCurrentSession()) {
        factory.openSession();
        System.out.println("Creating new student object...");
        Student tempStudent = new Student("Tomasz", "Jurek", "jur.tomasz13@gmail.com");
        System.out.println("Begin transaction");
        session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("Saving student..");
        session.save(tempStudent);
        System.out.println("Commiting transaction");
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("Transaction commited");
    }
}
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>Hibernate-Demo</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0.Beta3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>




</project>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23215605/10832295 this might answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Soo I used **Hibernate 6.0.0.3 Beta Version**, I changed it to latest non beta build (**5.6.4.Final**) and it worked.